# Распознавать цифры с нейросети

Tags: python, opencv

Подскажите как реализовать нейро сеть , что бы с камеры распознать текст (цифры) с распечатаного текста. Камера видит текст распознает в нем цифры и записывает результат в переменную. (для дальнейшей работы с этими данными) 
Будь те добры, подскажите как мне это реализовать. Или алгоритм для обучение нейро сети для цифр.
Хочу все это сделать на raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий пример кода. Возможно придется подогнать тренировочные данные под ваш шрифт
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python/20902310

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку, занимался с кодом но на этапе тестирование ошибки запуска кода. Думаю в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Показывайте трейс ошибки